# Aligning Div inside another Div

Tags: css, html, position

You can visit the site I am working on [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20140304201224/http://www.thomashall.idesignclass.com:80/). Currently, I am working on making the site relative. I am adjusting the CSS for a resolution with a width less than 820px. This involves adjusting the menu from this [image: pic of navigation at wide resolution]

to this [image: pic of navigation at narrow resolution]. As you can see, I have outlined my divs with a red border to demonstrate the problem. I want to the menu bar to sink to the bottom of its parent div. However, setting it to `bottom: 0` nothing changes. How can I get the `div class="nav"` to sink to the bottom of `div class="header"` at a resolution of less than 820px?

Here is my HTML

```
<div class="header">
        <div id="narrow-logo"><a href="#"><img src="Images/pantry logo.png" width="536" height="348"></a></div>
        <div class="nav">
                <ul>
                    <li class="link"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                    <li class="link"><a href="#">MENU</a></li>
                    <li id="logo"><a href="#"><img src="Images/pantry logo.png" width="536" height="348"></a></li>
                    <li class="link"><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
                    <li class="link"><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
                </ul>        
           </div>
      </div>
```

And my CSS

```
.header {
    width: 960px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    padding: 100px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.header div#narrow-logo {
    display: none;
}

.nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: 70px;
}

#logo a img {
    max-width: 250px;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

#logo { 
    width: 250px; 
    position: relative;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1080px) {
.header {
    width: 700px;
    height: 125px;
    padding: 75px 0px 0px 0px;
}

#logo a img {
    max-width: 180px;
}

#logo { 
    width: 180px; 
}

@media screen and (max-width: 820px) {
.header {
    border: 2px solid red;
    width: 475px;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 40px;
    height: 200px;
}

.header div#narrow-logo {
    border: 2px solid red;
    display: inherit;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%);
    transform: translate(-50%);
}

.header div#narrow-logo a img {
    width: 200px;
    height: auto;
}

.nav {
    border: 2px solid red;
    bottom: 0px;
}

.nav ul li {
    margin-right: 25px; 
}

.nav ul li:nth-child(3) {
    display: none;
}

#logo a img {
    display: none;
}

#logo { 
    width: 0; 
}
```

I know that is a lot of code and I apologize. I just wanted to make sure I included all positioning attributes that could be causing my issue. Let me know if I can clarify anything, and I appreciate your time and advice.

Comment: Do you actually want your logo to cover the text of Menu and Contact as it appears in that photo as well, or do you mean for that to all be behind the menus?

Comment: @Gyhth No, that's precisely why I want to attach the `div class="nav"` to the bottom of the `div class="header"`. I want to leave the `div id="narrow-logo"` at the top of the parent div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `bottom:0` to work, you need the element that it's being applied to to be absolutely positioned. You also need, in this case, to have it's parent relatively positioned. Try this:

```
.nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 70px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I implemented your advice in this way `.nav {
 bottom: 0px;
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
}` And it's great. As soon as I can, I will mark your answer correct.

Answer (score 0):

Adding position value will resolve your issue.Please update your css in the following section.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 820px) {
.nav {
border: 2px solid red;
bottom: 0px;
position:absolute;
left:16%;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For bottom:0; to work, your class="nav" has to have absolute positioning.

CSS:

```
.nav {
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
```